# Cakephp Blog Tutorial - Edit Routine

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In the cakephp blog tutorial in the Edit Post `edit()` action section

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

I can't understand why this `echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));`
 is included in the `cakephp/posts/edit/` (edit.cpt) while it works just fine without it?

Comment: That's how cake knows what row of the database (identified by an id) you are trying to edit

Comment: but I tried to remove that line and it works just fine, that's why I'm confused because in the `PostsController` it already Identified the row to edit why add `echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));` in the `edit` view?

Comment: There's two part of edit(): show edit form, and do the edit data if HTTP method is POST or PUT $this->request->is(array('post', 'put')). So we need to know the id.

Comment: without this ,it wont update the record, it will just add a new record

Comment: No it did not add a new record, it updated the existing record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to answer with a reason, but I think you're right - it can work just fine without.

My only guess is that it shows you how to do it this way so you can see how you would do it regardless if you're on the posts/edit/[id] page.

For example, you could edit 3 posts per page or edit a post on any other page...etc.  By passing the 'id' field, you don't have to submit the form to an action requiring the id.

I realize this isn't the best answer, but I'm not sure there is a better one.